# Finding last char appearance in string

Tags: python, string

If have this input:

```
/Users/myMac/Desktop/MemoryAccess/BasicTest.asm/someStuff
```

and i want to find the last time the char  `"/"` appeared, and get the string `BasicTest`

what is a good way of doing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module provides basic path name manipulations.

```
>>> from os.path import *
>>> file = '/Users/myMac/Desktop/MemoryAccess/BasicTest.asm/someStuff'
>>> splitext(basename(dirname(file)))[0]
'BasicTest'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = "/Users/myMac/Desktop/MemoryAccess/BasicTest.asm/someStuff"
>>> ind = s.rfind('/')
>>> ind1 = s[:ind].rfind('/')
>>> print(s[ind1+1:ind].split('.')[0])
BasicTest
```

Comment: The poster doesn't want the position of the final "/", he wants the path component that precedes it.

Answer (score 3):

here is an exmple with os:

```
>>> p = '/Users/myMac/Desktop/MemoryAccess/BasicTest.asm/someStuff'
>>> os.path.dirname(p)
'/Users/myMac/Desktop/MemoryAccess/BasicTest.asm'
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.dirname(p))
('/Users/myMac/Desktop/MemoryAccess/BasicTest', '.asm')
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(os.path.dirname(p))[0])
'BasicTest'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, "BasicTest" follows the next-to-last appearance of "/", but beyond that, try [`rfind`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind).

Answer (score 1):

The following will return `BasicTest.asm` which is half the battle:

```
'/Users/myMac/Desktop/MemoryAccess/BasicTest.asm/someStuff'.split('/')[-2]
```

The same trick can be used to split on the '.'

```
'BasicTest.asm'.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: The `os.path` functions are better for the purpose as they offer higher level of abstractions.  For example, they consider or `/` or `\\` separator depending on the OS thus making the code more portable.

Comment: @pepr I never said it wasn't. The question was about finding a specific portion of a string, even if a file path was used as the example.

Comment: OK. But this would be rather philosophical discussion of what was the core of the question.  You know that people often do not ask correctly because they do not know exactly what they really need.  This is natural the same way as your argument.  I do not want to make your answer less valid or my better.  But it may help the asker and the other students to notice the subtle difference and to become better ;)

Answer (score 0):

with re in python

```
import re
s = "/Users/myMac/Desktop/MemoryAccess/BasicTest.asm/someStuff"
pattern = re.compile(r"/(\w+)\.\w+/\w*$")
match = re.search(pattern,s)
print match.group(1)
```